# Cancel form closing by user selection

Tags: vb.net

In a vb.net windows application, I need user to confirm before closing application. I have this code in `FormClosing` event

```
If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
    Dim UserSelection As Integer = MsgBox("Do you want Cancel Processing and Exit Application?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Exit Application")
    If UserSelection = 6 Then
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        ????
    End If
End If
```

How can I cancel form closing if user clicked `No`?

Tried `e.Cancel = false` but it didn't work (exits application).

Comment: `e.Cancel = True` would stop the form closing.

Comment: @keyboardP Thanks.. I have mistakenly put the other way around, Sorry about my stupidity...:)

Comment: @keyboardP Put your previous comment as a answer I'll accept it.

Comment: e.Cancel = True stop form closing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.Cancel = True` would stop the form closing.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation "e.Cancel = True" PREVENTS the form from closing

Answer (score 0):

This is full code for cancel form closed. We should use FormClosing Event.

```
Private Sub Frm1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to closed", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```